# MaxDegreeOfParallelism Not Applying to list of Tasks?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, task, parallel.foreach

I have a list of tasks that I want to execute in parallel but in a limited fashion, almost like batching without me having to manage it. My approach was to use Parallel.ForEach and the MaxDegreeOfParallelism property of ParallelOptions. I'm finding that no matter what I set the value to, all of the tasks start at the same time. This is undesired behavior. I want the amount of tasks that are executing concurrently to be equal to the property. I wrote a simple example for illustration

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var numbers = Enumerable.Range(1, 5);
        var tasks = new List<Task>();

        foreach (int number in numbers)
        {
            tasks.Add(new Task(() => {Console.WriteLine("Starting thread {0} at time {1}. Starting delay...", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, DateTime.Now);
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            Console.WriteLine("{0} is done at {1}.", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, DateTime.Now);}));
        }

        Parallel.ForEach(tasks, new ParallelOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 2 }, t =>
        {
            t.Start();
        });

        Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
    }
}
```

Here's the output:
[image: Console Output]

Is my approach or understanding incorrect?

Comment: After reading the documentation and some other questions - I share your understanding, it should be working. I hope someone knows the answer, this one will bug me for a while.

Comment: Hi Seapoe, MaxDegreeOfParallelism affects the number of threads that can run concurrently. It does not determine when each thread starts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are a bit confused, the max degree of parallellism is applied to the quantity of tasks used by the parallel ForEach but inside you're creating new tasks, these aren't controlled by the ParallelOptions but by the TaskScheduler.

If you want to limit the number of concurrent tasks you must create a custom TaskScheduler and limit the number of tasks running.

[Here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualizeparallel/2011/02/14/a-taskscheduler-that-limits-the-number-of-threads/) you can find an example.

Comment: Interesting. So in my example if I remove the creation of new tasks and place the executing code inside of the parallel loop, would that achieve what I'm looking for?

Comment: Yes, it should.

Comment: Yep that worked! Thank you very much! I'll also look into the custom scheduler.